# Cannot fit autocomplete search result inside HTML table with Jquery, Ajax, JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-boot

So I have this [App](https://github.com/Georges73/Springboot-jquery-mysql-autocomplete/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/product/index.jsp) using AJAX technique with jQuery library to call the Spring-boot REST controller method. The app works but I cant make the searchresult to fit inside HTML tables.

[image] result [image]

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <p>Type a product</p>
        <label for="automplete-1">Tags: </label>
        <input type="text" id="productName">
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<!-- <br> Result -->

<br>

<div class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="result_table">

    <table style="width: 50%;">

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#productName')
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath }/product/search',
            /* declare sourc variable */

            select: function(event, ui) {
                /* click event dans ui to fire method*/
                /* alert(event) */

                var inputFromBox = ui.item.label;
                var searchResults = [];
                var html_to_append = '';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath }/product/search_full?inputParam=' + inputFromBox,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);

                        $.each(response, function(i, item) {

                            html_to_append += '<tr>';

                            html_to_append += '<td >' + item.id + '</td>';
                            html_to_append += '<td>' + item.name + '</td>';
                            html_to_append += '<td>' + item.description + '</td>';
                            html_to_append += '<td>' + item.price + '</td>';
                            html_to_append += '</tr>';

                        });

                        $("#result_table table").append(html_to_append);
                    },

                });

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I wonder how can 2k rep user post a question with that code formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your element with the id `result_table` is a `<div>`, NOT a table.

```
<div class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="result_table">

    <table style="width: 50%;">

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

So, you will need to change:

```
$("#result_table").append(html_to_append);
```

to

```
$("#result_table table").append(html_to_append);
```

Comment: It looks already different but still doesnt fit. See updated image. Thank anyway

Comment: @georgesvan You can check again with css `text-align` property. Something like you table header align is in `center` and your table body align is in `left`.